# KDE Notifications bubble it is shown as an square after upgrading to kubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma-5

After upgrading to Kubuntu 20.04.1 (from 18.04) the notification display is shown in an square box.

[image]

I guess this is not normal behavior. How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to the Dunst app was installed.

[image: KDE dunst notification]

After uninstalling it and moving back the notification widget to the taskbar everything went to normal.

```
sudo apt remove dunst
```

And killed it ,then restarted the plasmashell

```
killall plasmashell ; plasmashell &
```

[image: KDE default notification widget]